# TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'error'

Tags: node.js, express

I am following book 'Node.js In Action' one earlier access version from http://www.manning.com/cantelon/ and the author uses method 'error()' on 'res' object in section about Express. So, the following code that copied from book:

```
exports.required = function(field){
    field = parseField(field);
    return function(req, res, next){
        if (getField(req,field)){
            next()
        } else {
            res.error(field.join(' ') + ' is required');
...
```

However, this breaks with the error:

```
TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'error'
```

From Node.js docs, i see there is no method for response object. I wonder if there is a middlware that decorates 'res' object with the missing method error() that i need to include. Here is the current configurations:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3001);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.set('photos', __dirname + '/public/photos');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
  app.use(express.cookieSession());
  app.use(user);
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});
```

If there is none, but you know how to decorate the response object with method error(), I would appreciate if you could share the code snippet for it. thank you

Comment: Are you using same versions as is used in the book?

Comment: Esailija, i think i do. In the book, it states Express '3.x' and I am using Express "3.1.0"

Comment: Esailija, i noticed that the next version V16, all of the code examples with res.error() has been taken out,however. I find it useful to know and good for learning

Comment: You should use `res.send(statusCode, data)` instead.